# How to convert string (name of a variable) to a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, string, variables

Is it somehow possible to use a string as an actual variable name?
Sothing like this:

```
$a = '$myvariable[\'subitem\']';
```

How can I convert variable `$a` in order to actually work with a variable

```
$myvariable['subitem'] ?
```

EXAMPLE:

```
$myvariable['subitem'] = "hello";

$a = '$myvariable[\'subitem\']';

// do somenthing with $a

echo $a  // outputs "hello" instead of $myvariable['subitem']
```

Comment: You want the variable name to be the value of `$myvariable['subitem']`?

Comment: What's wrong with using `$item = 'subitem'; $myarray[$item]`? (The goal is unclear to me.)

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
$a = 'myvariable["subitem"]';
echo $$a;
```

Above is called [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: I think you dont get me right..

Comment: You mean $$a = "something new";

Comment: the $a is supposed to contain just a name of a varible..

Comment: I mean to use strings (that represent the names of variables) to get the actual variables..

Comment: @Totallama use $$a like I described. Try my answer

Comment: Thanks GGio, I guess you are right.. I'll go try it..

Comment: And conversely? Can I get somehow a name of a variable to string?

Comment: @Totallama yes use single quotes instead of double or just remove $ sign.

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work anyway..

Comment: Did you really try it? I mean: $a = 'myvariable["subitem"]';
echo $$a;